# Inserting a picture with AddPicture giving me an "argument not optional" error

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to write a code that inserts a picture into a cell based on the width of the cell (maintaining aspect ratio and changing the height of the cell to fit the picture).

It gives me compile error

> "argument not optional"

at the "AddPicture" line.

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long
Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3
Dim fileExplorer As fileDialog
Dim sFilePath As String
Dim Picture As Shape

emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


If MsgBox("Would you like to add a picture?", vbYesNo, "Add a Picture") = vbYes Then

    Set fileExplorer = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fileExplorer

        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.png; *.jpg; *.jpeg", 1
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then

            MsgBox "Canceled"

        Else

            sFilePath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
            Set Picture = Sheet1.Shapes.AddPicture(sFilePath, msoFalse, msoCTrue)
            With Picture

                .LockAspectRatio = True
                .Left = Sheet1.Cells(emptyRow, 6).Left
                .Top = Sheet1.Cells(emptyRow, 6).Top
                .Width = Sheet1.Range(Cells(emptyRow, 6)).Width
                Sheet1.Rows(Picture.TopLeftCell.Row).RowHeight = .Height

            End With
        End If

    End With

    Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you included information about which line specifically caused the error.

Comment: Apologies, it occurs in the line "Set Picture = Sheet1.Shapes.AddPicture" line. I have edited the post to reflect that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Set Picture = Sheet1.Shapes.AddPicture(sFilePath, msoFalse, msoCTrue, 100, 100, 100, 100)
```